# How do you insert a blob into a Cassandra column family?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am trying to run the following command in cqlsh:

```
cqlsh:testreducedb> INSERT INTO commits (hash, tid, keyframe) VALUES (0b5db8b91bfdeb0a304b372dd8dda123b3fd1ab6, now(), true);
```

I am guessing that I am getting an error because the column `hash` is of type `blob` but I am trying to insert that commit hash 0b5db8b91bfdeb0a304b372dd8dda123b3fd1ab6.

How do you insert this in cqlsh?

Also I am getting the following error when running that command:

```
Bad Request: line 1:63 mismatched character '1' expecting '-'
```

Not very helpful to me, don't really know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blob literal must be started with "0x"

```
INSERT INTO commits (hash, tid, keyframe) VALUES (0x0b5db8b91bfdeb0a304b372dd8dda123b3fd1ab6, now(), true);
```

Comment: You may also use typeAsBlob() functions for the same